# Heroku webapp - Random "Application Error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, application-error

Launched few weeks ago my web appp developed with ROR 3 and deployed on Heroku. Problem is, sometimes it works perfectly well, sometimes it doesn't, got this message error:

```
APPLICATION ERROR
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Below the logs

```
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830067+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830069+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830071+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830080+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830083+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830086+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830088+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830090+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830091+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830094+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830093+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830096+00:0
0 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block
in start_thread'
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830113+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830114+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-27T20:08:42.830455+00:00 app[web.1]: Served asset /bg_white.png - 404 No
t Found (1ms)
2014-04-27T20:08:43.162123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/libert
e.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=7b9771f3-85bb-4496-9fb4-2b4eec
2102fe fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=
177
2014-04-27T20:08:43.525022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/chorou
k.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=b8b7e7be-d574-421d-8049-81e620
9a7cf8 fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=304 bytes
=177
2014-04-27T20:08:43.673843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/sawt.j
pg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=143b6e6b-12a7-4f6c-97d0-9a8964af7
ccf fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=177

2014-04-27T20:08:43.986517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ennaha
r.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=6cbab6c6-0f90-4c32-afdb-ceca35
71f02e fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10ms status=304 bytes
=177
2014-04-27T20:08:44.066184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/kabyli
e.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=695c496d-17c2-47e1-977f-88cfcc
8c5655 fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=
177
2014-04-27T20:08:44.083568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/moudja
hid.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=3a2c5222-83b4-44b2-8ce2-0c5e
55a893f2 fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 byte
s=177
2014-04-27T20:08:44.293919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/expres
sion.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=b73c7622-1539-468d-b187-ec8
266c815ad fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 byt
es=177
2014-04-27T20:08:44.392924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/matin.
jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=b2d2cfb2-99d5-49df-839e-6cf6f5ea
04fa fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=17
7
2014-04-27T20:08:44.711684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/heddaf
.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=b1d646ac-4312-422f-a3f2-536c01d
e22ea fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms st
atus=304 bytes=177
2014-04-27T20:08:44.784743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/buteur
.jpg host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=f2e8c8cb-408b-43ed-af0a-ea5b2e0
a31e7 fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=1
77
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941357+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/assets/bg_linklist.jpg"):
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941352+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941360+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941361+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941363+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941366+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941371+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941365+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941369+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941376+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941377+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941379+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941380+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941397+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941399+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941400+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941402+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941404+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941406+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941409+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941412+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941413+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941415+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941416+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941418+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-27T20:08:44.941754+00:00 app[web.1]: Served asset /bg_linklist.jpg - 404
Not Found (1ms)
2014-04-27T20:09:29.009593+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.202.206
at 2014-04-27 20:09:29 +0000
2014-04-27T20:09:29.012234+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T20:10:43.370389+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 74358ms (Views:
4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-27T20:10:43.368565+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb with
in layouts/application (2.4ms)
2014-04-27T20:17:48.804044+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.202.206
at 2014-04-27 20:17:48 +0000
2014-04-27T20:17:48.807006+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T20:18:18.801647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
timeout" method=GET path=/ host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=6c668e92
-de50-42fc-81b5-285b1dba27dc fwd="41.108.202.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service
=30002ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-04-27T20:19:03.564586+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb with
in layouts/application (43.1ms)
2014-04-27T20:19:03.566877+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 74760ms (Views:
46.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-27 20:26:13] ERROR Errno::
ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581175+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `write'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581195+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:in `send_body_string'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581196+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:in `send_body'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581198+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:in `send_response'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581200+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in `run'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581202+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581193+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `_write_data'
2014-04-27T20:26:13.581178+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `<<'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060892+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-27 20:34:34] ERROR Errno::
ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060898+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `write'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060900+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `<<'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060902+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:in `_write_data'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060904+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:in `send_body_string'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060905+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:in `send_body'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060907+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:in `send_response'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060909+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in `run'
2014-04-27T20:34:34.060910+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-27T21:05:24.955061+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.197.242
at 2014-04-27 21:05:24 +0000
2014-04-27T21:05:24.957646+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T21:05:54.956160+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
timeout" method=GET path=/ host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=19316b43
-19c6-4094-a814-695b337d1eb9 fwd="41.108.197.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service
=30004ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-04-27T21:08:29.588356+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb with
in layouts/application (2.3ms)
2014-04-27T21:08:29.590249+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 184632ms (Views
: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-27T21:10:26.746380+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.197.242
at 2014-04-27 21:10:26 +0000
2014-04-27T21:10:26.748717+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T21:10:56.747149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
timeout" method=GET path=/ host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=a33de624
-f5fb-4477-96c6-103f45066944 fwd="41.108.197.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service
=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-04-27T21:11:07.582910+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 40834ms (Views:
5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-27T21:11:07.586686+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T21:11:07.584462+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.197.242
at 2014-04-27 21:11:07 +0000
2014-04-27T21:11:07.580958+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb with
in layouts/application (2.4ms)
2014-04-27T21:11:21.194238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
timeout" method=GET path=/ host=dz-break-actu.herokuapp.com request_id=5c611ecb
-22b4-432c-aef7-fed28aec63d4 fwd="41.108.197.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service
=30012ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-04-27T21:11:46.354300+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb with
in layouts/application (2.3ms)
2014-04-27T21:11:46.359717+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index
as HTML
2014-04-27T21:11:46.357470+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.108.197.242
at 2014-04-27 21:11:46 +0000
2014-04-27T21:11:46.356122+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 38769ms (Views:
4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I couldn’t figure out the problem reading the logs, any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bg_linklist.jpg")

ERROR Errno:: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused

Completed 200 OK in 74358ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) #-> 74000ms? Really?
```

Unless you're trying to load some heavy assets, you've some serious issues with your stack. Can you detail which database you're using, as I think this could be the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is, I am not using any database, the webapp scrapes some headlines from various websites, and appear on my application, directly. Below an example from my Controller.rb:
  
    docwatan = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.elwatan.com/"))
    @watan = {}
    docwatan.xpath('//div[5]/h3/a').each do |link|
    @watan[link.text.strip] = link['href']
    
What I can't figure out, that even when the application works perfectly well, I got the same error into logs, like "ERROR Errno:: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused", is it common ?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated